# Html file not modifed in saved version

Tags: php, html

This snippet of code is not doing what I expect it to do. It's part of code I've written to find and update links in thousands of html pages. Those links lead to pages that used to contain %20 in the file name

e.g. $origlink_url = "fred%20flinstone.html"
$newlink_url = "fred-flinstone.html."

```
<?php

// preceeding code removed
 
//load file that contains link to auto edit it before resaving
$file = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/active/'.$link_array[$z][1][1]); 
//update via 'find & replace'   
$file2 = str_replace($origlink_url, $newlink_url, $file); 
//test to visually affirm file is modified (3 code lines below)
$w=strpos($file2, $newlink_url); 
$v=strlen($newlink_url); 
echo nl2br(" strpos of link: ".$w." link strlen is: ".$v." File substring: ".substr($file2,$w,$v)."  ");
//end of test code
$fh = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/modified-files/".$link_array[$z][1][1], "w"); 
fwrite($fh, $file2);
fclose($fh);
echo nl2br("Page updated: ".$link_array[$z][1][1]." \n"); 

?>
```

It succesfully loads the html file, and confirms onscreen that the link in file2 has been changed (replaces '%20' in the link with '-') and confirms correctly the links location within the file via the number of chars before the link.
The save of the html has the correct timestamp and it succesfully either writes a new file or overwrites an old file. Yet somehow the link within the saved html file still has '%20'. Seems impossible to me?

Comment: I think str_replace doesn't happens as it expected
but you can view the changes while printing because browser convert your html entities.

Comment: try print $file2 with `htmlentities` function

Comment: Thankyou, you solved the problem by making me realise that when php loads an .html file, 'http: and .html are treated differently to a template.

Comment: When php loads an .html file, an extracted char string that contains '.html' is treated differently, which caused the replacement string to be inserted elsewhere in the string.

I then tried just finding a match of the  file name within the link and replacing it, but excluding  the '.html' at the end of the link and it all worked as expected.

$file2 = str_replace($origlinkFileName, $newlinkFileName, $file); 

If I need to change the file type in such situations then I'll try your suggestion in the second comment.